# Extending a visa-free stay in the Philippines

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, visa-extensions, philippines

> BI IMPLEMENTS VISA-FREE SCHEME FOR INDIANS
>
> JUNE 21, 2012
>
> Indian nationals who are regular international travelers may now enter the country without a visa and stay here for 14 days, the Bureau of Immigration (BI) said.
>
> Immigration Commissioner Ricardo David Jr. said he had issued a memorandum circular allowing Indian nationals to enter the Philippines visa-free so long as they are holders of a valid visa from the European Union (EU) or any of six other countries.
>
> Aside from EU’s Schengen visa, David said the visa-free entry privilege may also be availed by an Indian with a visa from either the United States, Canada, Japan, Australia, Singapore, and United Kingdom.
>
> “Indian nationals who avail of this scheme will be granted an initial
> stay of 14 days, which may be extended for an additional seven days,”
> the BI chief explained.

http://www.sunstar.com.ph/breaking-news/2012/06/21/indians-can-enter-philippines-sans-visa-21-days-227996

What is the procedure of extending the visa from a 14 day visa to a 21 day visa?

Comment: Are you asking about the USA visa waiver program or some kind of Schengen visa waiver?

Comment: @hippietrail He's talking about a Philippines visa.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: If the Philippines also has a visa waiver program, this illustrates the problem I had some months back when we ended up with the US-centric [tag:visa-waiver-program] tag. HaLaBi just made this new tag after we chatted about in the chat room.

Comment: Ah yes we also had this [tag:visa-free-entry] tag. I still think the division between it and [tag:visa-waiver-program] for US-only is not helpful and likely to confuse.

Comment: @hippietrail, getting off-topic a bit, but perhaps we could just have ESTA for the US, and visa-waiver for cases like this? Can discuss in [chat]

Comment: @freethinker - if you could actually put the detail in your question, rather than just a link, that'd be useful.  While it may work now, that link could be removed one day and it'd render the question mostly useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the Bureau of Immigration, Philippines about the procedure for extension of VISA. Please note that this information is valid for extension of all kind of Visa, and not specific to a certain category.

> **How would I extend my visa?**
>
> You may get an application form from the Visa Extension Section located at the ground floor Annex building,
> Bureau of Immigration. Fill up the form, provide a photocopy of your
> passport, visa, latest arrival card, valid extension of stay, if any
> and other pertinent documents which will support your application.

**[Extension fee after initial admission of 7/14 days of authorized stay](http://immigration.gov.ph/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=118&Itemid=43)**

```
PARTICULARS                                   AMOUNTS
Visa Waiver Application Fee                        P 1,000.00 
Visa Waiver Fee                                    P 500.00
Certificate Fee                                    P 500.00 
Express Fee                                        P 1,000.00
Legal Research Fee (LRF) for each immigration Fee  P 30.00
Total                                              P 3,030.00
```

One special piece of information to pay attention to, while visiting Bureau of Immigration offices:

> All applicants for extension are required to dress properly.
> Applicants wearing shorts, sandos, and slippers will not be allowed
> entry to Immigration Office.

Comment: So I went through this procedure of visa extension and it works without a glitch. You have to go to the Bureau of Immigration (http://goo.gl/maps/3XG8J) and follow the procedure listed above.